# Application Insights for .NET Core only shows debug level worse than "warning"

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights

I have a .NET Core 2.1 application (Web API) where I added logging providers for the Console and ApplicationInsights.
I followed the instructions from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) article to learn, how the logger works. Later I added ApplicationInsights Provider what I learned from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core) example.

My configuration file just looks like that:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace"
    }
  },
```

Nothing else.
I expect to get all log messages to appear in ApplicationInsights, but however only warning messages, error messages and critical messages appear there.
All logs with level < warning does not appear there.

If I add a specific log level "debug" for ApplicationInsights, this also does not work.

Any ideas what I might do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read thoroughly the documentation page that you posted, in the sub-section

[ILogger logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core)

it is stated that the default logging level is `=< Warning`.

You will find an official Microsoft link on how to change minimum logging levels [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#control-logging-level).

What you need to do to change log level for Application Insights is set your configuration file like below:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "If levels are specified in Logging.{providername}.LogLevel, they override anything set in Logging.LogLevel." For me that means that if I keep the providers log level empty, this takes the default configuration from above. However this seems not to be the case. Only if I explicitly add LogLevel.Default = "Debug" in ApplicationInsights-Section the log level is shown...